# Retrieving Images memory usage

Tags: ios, memory

My app has problems with memory management. I have used instruments and have noticed that allocation just builds itself up until it crashes. I am using ARC. When I open the app it starts with 97.13 mb memory.  I want to see if this piece of code is efficient, if there is something that is causing the memory build up. 
**Update**
According to Instruments when I open the app, the app is using 93.17mb. As I try to display the collection view(OthersViewController) multiple times memory gradually increases 1mb every time.  After taking a picture(OthersCamera) and going back to the view controller,  the memory flings up from 106.87mb to 158.38mb. AND strangely after this when I try to display the picture again(OthersViewController) the memory just flings up even more from 158.38 mb to 215.24mb. Recieving a low memory warning and crash.

Github:https://github.com/canoneoskiss/name/tree/master

Comment: when does it crash? after you press a button? or just on it's own? What is the app doing?

Comment: Ok Thanks for commenting,  My app is basically taking a picture and showing it in a collection view.  It does not crash straight away but however if I try to display the collection view several times the memory just goes up and up as like a mountain and crashes.  If you want to see a specific code,  please tell me, I would gladly share it since I'm really stuck in this problem.

Comment: Try to narrow it down until you can see at exactly which point you get a build up. Where exactly does it jump? after you take the picture? when you add it to the CollectionView? When you display the connection View?

Comment: Ok, it jumps when I go to view controller to collection view and also after taking a picture and going back to the view controller.  The View Controller is like a hub that I can choose to display the collection view or take a picture.

Comment: Do you pass data to and send data from that ViewController? Do you get a jump when passing to or passing from there? Let's narrow it down all the way. Let's find the exact method.

Comment: Thank you, I do not send the data from the View Controller. If you want to see my code part of it is on git hub [here](https://github.com/canoneoskiss/name/tree/master)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abandoned memory and crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595128/abandoned-memory-and-crash)

Comment: Have you found the method that causes the build up? I think you have a single place in which you are most likely doubling or tripling your memory. Where EXACTLY does the build up occur? Your questio needs to look like this: "When I press buttonOne, it jumps 45 MB. Here is the code for buttonOne"

Comment: I updated my question for more detail.

Comment: Are you ever calling `[UIImage imageWithName:]`?

Comment: And you're probably leaking `OthersViewController` and/or `OthersCamera`.

Comment: Yes,  I have it in my code, you can check iron git hub aswell.

Comment: There was no leak when I used the instrument app to find out.

Comment: How ares you going back and forth between your controllers? Are you using segues?

Comment: no I am not its on story board I am not passing on data.

Comment: Then how are you going back and forth? Also, when you post your project, you should post the whole thing not just the individual files, so we can see the storyboard, and test the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code, and your storyboard is a big mess. Your problem is due to the way you move between controllers. You're going backwards in the storyboard with segues, and you shouldn't do that. When you go backwards with a segue, you're not going back to the controller you came from, you're instantiating a new instance of that controller. Except for unwind segues, segues ALWAYS instantiate new controllers. Since the presenting controller and the presented controller in a modal segue have strong pointers to each other, none of these controllers ever gets deallocated.

To fix this, you need to redo your storyboard. Either use unwind segues to go backwards, or dismiss any modal controllers in code (no segue) with dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:.

Comment: Thank you for a great advice,  I never thought about the story board and was to focused in the camera coding,  Would unwind segues help the memory usage?

Comment: @user3104325, yes they would, because when you go backwards with an unwind segue the controller you segue from (and any in between there and the destination controller) will be deallocated, and their memory freed up.

Comment: @user3104325, what actions are you doing that cause the build up? I can't really test the app since it has to be run-on a device to take pictures, and I don't have the provisioning files to run it. The controllers in the drawers (hats, coats, tops, etc.) are properly deallocated now when you push the back button. ViewController will never be since it's the rootViewController of the navigation controller which is the window's root view controller. I can't test any of the others.

Comment: I am suspecting the icarouselexampleviewcontroller.  When I push that it jumps to 103mb then goes back down to around 60mb.  Also the camera still has troubles.  It does dealloc but it still builds up memory which leads to crash.

Comment: @user3104325, the carousel controller spikes the memory usage but it doesn't stay up when you go back, so I don't think that's the problem. Unfortunately, I can't test the camera controllers.

Answer (score 0):

After capturing image change its pixels because in iPhone 1 image will be @ 8MB. Even i faced this issue. use below code. after capturing image send it to this method it will return a low memory image.

+(UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect forImageViewRect:(CGSize)imageVwRect{

```
//  UIImage *tempImage;
// tempImage=[self scaleImage:imageToCrop toSize:imageVwRect];

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

//  cropped=[self scaleImage:cropped toSize:rect.size];
return cropped;
```

}

or

+(UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image  size:(int)maxSize
 {

```
//  int kMaxResolution = 640; // Or whatever

int kMaxResolution = maxSize; // Or whatever

CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = roundf(bounds.size.width / ratio);
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = roundf(bounds.size.height * ratio);
    }
}
CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
CGFloat boundHeight;
UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
switch(orient) {

    case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
        boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
        bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
        break;

    default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];
}
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
}
else {
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
}

CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageCopy;
```

}

Comment: It looks like a great solution which and where should i put this code in?Do I put Both?

Comment: imagepicker method will be called once you choose the image from camera or gallery . you will get the image in this method call the method i mentioned it will return an image. you can assign it to an image view or to an image and use the image to assign to image view

Comment: So... very confused..I should put both of these code in otherscamera.m ?? I put it under didReceiveMemoryWarning method

Comment: choose any one of them. in otherscamera.m  in the method where you will get image after capturing image. not in didReceiveMemoryWarning method

Comment: -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image1 =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *croppedImage =[UIImage scaleAndRotateImage:image1 :profilePicImageview.frame];
    profilePicImageview.image=croppedImage;
  
    //AAA  delegate.profilePicTempImage=croppedImage;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: if your image is still big in size  use this statement                UIImage *lowSizeImage=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(croppedImage, 1);